# jQuery password generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords

I have the following JS code that checks a password strength and also creates a random password as well. What I want to do is edit the code so that instead of putting the generated password inside the password field it will put it inside a span tag with say an id of randompassword. In addition that I would like it so that by default there will be a random password inside the span tag and then when the user clicks the button it will generate another one. And also move the link to be next to span tag rather than the password box.

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
$.fn.passwordStrength = function( options ){
 return this.each(function(){
  var that = this;that.opts = {};
  that.opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.passwordStrength.defaults, options);

  that.div = $(that.opts.targetDiv);
  that.defaultClass = that.div.attr('class');

  that.percents = (that.opts.classes.length) ? 100 / that.opts.classes.length : 100;

   v = $(this)
  .keyup(function(){
   if( typeof el == "undefined" )
    this.el = $(this);
   var s = getPasswordStrength (this.value);
   var p = this.percents;
   var t = Math.floor( s / p );

   if( 100 <= s )
    t = this.opts.classes.length - 1;

   this.div
    .removeAttr('class')
    .addClass( this.defaultClass )
    .addClass( this.opts.classes[ t ] );

  })
  .after('<a href="#">Generate Password</a>')
  .next()
  .click(function(){
   $(this).prev().val( randomPassword() ).trigger('keyup');
   return false;
  });
 });

 function getPasswordStrength(H){
  var D=(H.length);
  if(D>5){
   D=5
  }
  var F=H.replace(/[0-9]/g,"");
  var G=(H.length-F.length);
  if(G>3){G=3}
  var A=H.replace(/\W/g,"");
  var C=(H.length-A.length);
  if(C>3){C=3}
  var B=H.replace(/[A-Z]/g,"");
  var I=(H.length-B.length);
  if(I>3){I=3}
  var E=((D*10)-20)+(G*10)+(C*15)+(I*10);
  if(E<0){E=0}
  if(E>100){E=100}
  return E
 }

 function randomPassword() {
  var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$_+?%^&)";
  var size = 10;
  var i = 1;
  var ret = ""
  while ( i <= size ) {
   $max = chars.length-1;
   $num = Math.floor(Math.random()*$max);
   $temp = chars.substr($num, 1);
   ret += $temp;
   i++;
  }
  return ret;
 }

};

$(document)
.ready(function(){
 $('#password1').passwordStrength({targetDiv: '#iSM',classes : Array('weak','medium','strong')});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// you can use another improved version to generate password as follows

//Define
function wpiGenerateRandomNumber(length) {

    var i = 0;
    var numkey = "";
    var randomNumber;

    while( i < length) {

        randomNumber = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) % 94) + 33;

        if ((randomNumber >=33) && (randomNumber <=47)) { continue; }
        if ((randomNumber >=58) && (randomNumber <=90)) { continue; }
        if ((randomNumber >=91) && (randomNumber <=122)) { continue; }
        if ((randomNumber >=123) && (randomNumber <=126)) { continue; }

        i++;
        numkey += String.fromCharCode(randomNumber);

    }

    return numkey;

}

// Call

var myKey=wpiGenerateRandomNumber(10); // 10=length

alert(myKey);



// Output

2606923083
```

Comment: how is this improved?  You have a very heavy bias towards punctuation in this due to the `* 100 % 94` logic.  There's also no reason to use `String.fromCharCode` instead of a list of characters...

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$(this).prev().val( randomPassword() ).trigger('keyup');
```

is inserting the value after a click. So you can change that value to stick the password wherever you want it. For example you could change it to:

```
$('span#randompassword').html(randomPassword());
```

You could also run this when the page loads to stick something in that span right away:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('span#randompassword').html(randomPassword());
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
     $('span#randompassword').html(randomPassword());
}); Isn't working? the other part works great. Thanks

Comment: This is what I have at the moment:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ptest').passwordStrength({ targetDiv: '#iSM', classes: Array('weak', 'medium', 'strong') });
    //$('span#randompassword strong').text(randomPassword());
});

I have had to comment out that line because it caused the link Generate Password link to disappear and doesn't work either.

Comment: $('span#randompassword strong').text(randomPassword()) will call randomPassword and write the value it returns as text inside any <strong> tag inside a span with id randompassword. That's what that code mean. I'm afraid I can't debug your whole program for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Very simple method to generate random number; can be use to generate random password key as well


jq(document).ready( function() {

jq("#genCodeLnk").click( function() {

d = new Date();

t = d.getTime();

jq("#cstm_invitecode").val(t);

});

});
```