# jquery or javascript password generator with at least a capital and a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords

How would one need to modify one of these examples, to have at least a capital and a nubmer inside the password?

[jQuery password generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477862/jquery-password-generator)

http://javascript.internet.com/passwords/password-generator.html

http://www.blazonry.com/javascript/password.php

or any other example :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

off the top of my head:

```
function generatePassword(len){
    var pwd = [], cc = String.fromCharCode, R = Math.random, rnd, i;
    pwd.push(cc(48+(0|R()*10))); // push a number
    pwd.push(cc(65+(0|R()*26))); // push an upper case letter

    for(i=2; i<len; i++){
       rnd = 0|R()*62; // generate upper OR lower OR number
       pwd.push(cc(48+rnd+(rnd>9?7:0)+(rnd>35?6:0)));
    }

    // shuffle letters in password
    return pwd.sort(function(){ return R() - .5; }).join('');
}
```